# Background colour in pyplot

Tags: matplotlib

I want to have three distinct regions in the background of my graph. I would also like to shade them so that at the boundaries between these regions I have a white color. I have a workaround for this as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
sfig = fig.add_subplot(111)
nrec = 10
for i in range(300, 422):
    sfig.axvspan(i, i+1, facecolor='plum', alpha=(1-abs(i-((422.0-300.0)/2.0 + 300.0))/(422.0-300.0)*2.0)*0.6, edgecolor='plum', zorder = 0, lw = 0)
for i in range(423, 577):
    sfig.axvspan(i, i+1, facecolor='silver', alpha=(1-abs(i-((577-423)/2 + 423))/(577-423)*2)*0.6, edgecolor='silver', zorder = 0, lw = 0)
for i in range(578, 700):
    sfig.axvspan(i, i+1, facecolor='cyan', alpha=(1-abs(i-((700-578)/2 + 578))/(700-578)*2)*0.6, edgecolor='cyan', zorder = 0, lw = 0)
plt.show()
```

However, when I save this figure in the .pdf format I see some lines, presumably from the boundaries of these vertical rectangles. Is there a better solution for this? If not, is there a way to not have these annoying boundaries between rectangles?

Comment: Can't reproduce this, this produces three zones with no black lines between the rectangles

Comment: Hello. The lines are not black, but hopefully, you can see that the color change is not gradual. Maybe it is more visible if you save the figure in .pdf format?